# Parse the JSON into a data frame

Tags: r, json, dataframe

Parse the following JSON into a data frame.

```
js<-'{"name": null, "release_date_local": null, "title": "3 (2011)",
"opening_weekend_take": 1234, "year": 2011,
"release_date_wide": "2011-09-16", "gross": 59954}'
```

Comment: Please also show what you've tried and what the end result should look like.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
library(rjson)
data.frame(t(unlist(fromJSON(js))))
   title opening_weekend_take year release_date_wide gross
3 (2011)                 1234 2011        2011-09-16 59954
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(RJSONIO)
js<-'[{"name": null, "release_date_local": null, "title": "3 (2011)",
"opening_weekend_take": 1234, "year": 2011,
"release_date_wide": "2011-09-16", "gross": 59954}]'

js <- fromJSON(js)
```

Also replace nulls with NA

```
js <- lapply(js, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
```

Then finally use do.call method

```
asDataFrame <- do.call("rbind", lapply(js, as.data.frame))
```

OR

```
    do.call("rbind", js)
```

Output:

```
name release_date_local title      opening_weekend_take year  
[1,] NA   NA            "3 (2011)" "1234"               "2011"
     release_date_wide gross  
[1,] "2011-09-16"      "59954"
```